# How to create a shopping cart in php without database?

Tags: php

I need to display the products with add button to add it to the cart.
When user clicks the button, the product will to be removed from the list and appear in the cart section, which is below the section where the available products are displayed.

In the cart section we have the products in the cart and a button to remove the product from cart.
When user click the button, the product will to be removed from the cart section and displayed in the product section, which is above the cart section.

Answer (score 2):

For doing this, you can use the `$_SESSION['session_var_name']` variable.
When user click on the add to cart button store the values into session
and display those data from the session on the cart page.

At the cart page you can use the delete button for removing product from cart and for
doing this use `unset($_SESSION['session_var_name'])` .

I hope this will helps you.